# AWS Server - Data Lost

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, server

I was using aws to maintain one website. However, yesterday around 1PM, the server went off, and after a new instance has been created to supply the necessity (wrong type), it link to an old volume of data. Thus, I couldn't find now the correct volume to change it.

Can someone help me? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Tarcisiofl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AWS, under the ELASTIC BLOCK STORE section, on the volumes you can see all of your previous created volumes.

Link example: (Go to own zone and go to the volume section)

https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#Volumes:sort=desc:createTime